# Jboss deployment error: class A cannot access its superclass B

Tags: java, jboss

I'm pretty new to JBoss and I'm trying to deploy a .war file on JBoss version 7.0.6 GA.

The .war file is created with the "export as .war file" option in Eclipse.

If I deploy the same .war file on Tomcat, it works without any error.

When I deploy on Jboss, I came across this strange error:

```
2017-10-20 17:29:26,803 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Failed to link 
org/apache/log4j/xml/ExtXMLWatchdog (Module "deployment.
[MY_WAR_NAME].war:main" from Service Module Loader): class 
org.apache.log4j.xml.ExtXMLWatchdog cannot access its superclass 
org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog
```

I'm using the log4j-1.2.17.jar library inside my web app; also, I'm using another custom library named util-log4j.jar.

Inside the log4j-1.2.17.jar is defined the class org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog; inside the util-log4j.jar is defined the class 
org.apache.log4j.xml.ExtXMLWatchdog.

It seems that the ExtXMLWatchdog cannot see the XMLWatchdog defined in another .jar, but why?

Thank you,
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. Sharing the solution:

inside the .war file, in the WEB-INF folder, I put a file named

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>  
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" /> 
    </exclusions>  
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

It seems that JBoss is equipped with some standard library, but those libraries maybe are loaded by a different ClassLoader (not sure of this, however)

With that file, essentially I'm telling to JBoss to ignore it's own org.apache.log4j library.

The result is that my log4j library is used, and problem is gone!